# Register singleton in Prism 7.1 module if it is not already registered

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

My Prism 7.1 application uses 2 modules like plugins.

The `App : PrismApplication` registers a `IDataService` singleton that is always available

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IDataService, DataService>();
}
```

and both plugins can use it

```
public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
{
    _dataService = containerProvider.Resolve<IDataService>();
}
```

This is OK - both modules get the same instance of the object.

**But:**

Each of the two plugins also needs to use `IUsbStatus` singleton, but the main application does NOT know about it, I register it in the `MyModuleA : IModule` and also in `MyModuleB : IModule`:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IUsbStatus, UsbStatus>();
}
```

If I only use plugin A or plugin B, everything works fine, but if I use both plugins, then the `IUsbStatus` singleton is registered twice and when I resolve it, it does NOT give me the same instance of the object.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check whether the singleton is already registering before overriding the existing registration. Or you have to make sure to not resolve anything before everything is registered.

The latter option is clearly preferable but more difficult to achieve, so just check before registering the `UsbStatus`. The `IContainerRegistry` cannot do that, so you have to get your actual container and do some container-specific stuff, e.g. for unity:

```
using Prism.Unity;
[...]
if (!containerRegistry.GetContainer().IsRegistered<IUsbStatus>())
    containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IUsbStatus, UsbStatus>();
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between `IsRegistered` and `IsTypeRegistered` since both accept `System.Type`?

Comment: `IsTypeRegistered` come from Prism, `IsRegistered` and its generic variant (updating the answer) are from Unity itself. But they all should do the same thing, basically.

Comment: I have just now tried to use `IsTypeRegistered` in both modules and I can confirm that in my case it returns `false` both times. I will be using `IsRegistered` since it returns `true` the second time. Thank you!

Comment: NIce find - I have no idea, why `IsTypeRegistered` not just calls `IsRegistered` on the container...